# Storage quota has been exceeded for this service. You must either delete documents first, or use a higher SKU for additional quota

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In **azure search**  getting error sometimes not every time when I'm `create or update` index in **azure**.

and I'm tying post multiple data as per guideline [How to index large data sets in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-large-index)

is there any way to update existing data in `azure`? [How to rebuild an index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-reindex#how-to-rebuild-an-index)

Some `azure  Available tiers` [Available tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-sku-tier#available-tiers)

[image]

> Code this simple example

```
        private static SearchServiceClient searchServiceClient;

        public virtual void CreateSearchServiceClient()
        {
            searchServiceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials("APIKEY"));
        }

        public virtual Index CreateIndex()
        {
            CreateSearchServiceClient();
            Index index = new Index();
            string scoringProfile = "AzureSearchScoringProfile";

            // Create index if search client service is available
            if (searchServiceClient != null)
            {
                AzureSearchItem azureSearchItem = new AzureSearchItem();

                // Map index schema
                var definition = new Index()
                {
                    Name = IndexName,
                    Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<AzureSearchItem>(),
                    Suggesters = new List<Suggester>() {
                                        new Suggester()
                                        {
                                            Name = ConstantKeys.AzureSearchTopBarSuggestor,
                                            SourceFields = FormatSuggesterFields()
                                        }
                    }
                };

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scoringProfile))
                {
                    definition.ScoringProfiles = new List<ScoringProfile>()
                    {
                        new ScoringProfile()
                        {
                            Name =  scoringProfile
                        }
                    };
                }

                definition = SetAnalyzer(definition);

                // Create index
                index = searchServiceClient.Indexes.CreateOrUpdate(definition);
            }

            return index;
        }
```

Comment: How many indexes do you currently have in your Search account? Do these indexes contain data? If so, how many records?

Comment: Right now we have `3` index and per `index`, we have approx `50000` data

Comment: And you're using "Free" tier. Correct?

Comment: Yes, for demo purpose using **free tier **

Comment: And I have 50 MB space in free tier.